# Can I restrict access to S3 from a specific subdomain only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have several subdomains that will have their own S3 bucket. Is there a way to set S3 bucket to allow GET requests only from a specific subdomain?

Comment: Do you mean: you want all files in your S3 only accessible from a certain domain (HTTP referrer)? Or change the S3 bucket domain into your own domain?

Comment: @EdwardSamuel I want all the files in a bucket to be accessible only from a certain domain.

Answer (score 3):

Use an `aws:Referer` condition. From [Restricting Access to a Specific HTTP Referrer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4):

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originated from www.example.com and example.com",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```